# NVelocity syntax for calling methods with evaluated parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, nvelocity

I have a fairly simple template that I need to make a method call from. However, NVelocity does not seem to evaluate method parameters that themselves are **NVelocity variables**. Take the following NVelocity template:

```
#if (--- CONDITION SNIPPED ---)
    <blockquote class="column span-4">
          I MADE IT!
    </blockquote>
#else
    <blockquote class="column span-4">
         $extensionMethods.TestMethod(${var1})
</blockquote>       
#end
```

In the above template, `$extensionMethods` is passed in as an instance of a class and works wonderfully when passing in evaluated numbers (e.g. `$extensionMethods.TestMethod(4)` works every time). However, using `$var1` causes the entire string to be returned as-is: `$extensionMethods.TestMethod(${var1})`.

**Is there a way to pass in a variable to a method lazily to get the above template to evaluate correctly?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are having trouble, it's likely to be something to do with your variable types, or the method availability.  I've built and tested the following:

```
public class TestClass
{
    #region Methods
    public string DoSomething(string name)
    {
        return name.ToUpperInvariant();
    }

    public string DoSomethingElse(int age)
    {
        return (age*10).ToString();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

And my template:

```
#set($myVar = "matt")
#set($myVar2 = 10)

Name: $test.DoSomething(${myVar})
Age: $test.DoSomethingElse(${myVar2})
```

And the output:

```
Name: "MATT"
Age: 100
```

Can we see some code for your extension methods?

Comment: Thanks Matthew, I spent some more time tinkering with the code and realized that the example I've provided above is oversimplified. I've managed to fix the code, but I still do believe there is a bug within NVelocity. I'll explain in an post below.